# Opcode ff /4 which value is give to eip

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to simulate the operation of `jmp (opcode ff /4)`.
When referred to the Intel 80386 manual, I found this:

```
 IF instruction = near indirect JMP
 (* i.e. operand is r/m16 or r/m32 *)
 THEN
    IF OperandSize = 16
 THEN
     EIP <- [r/m16] AND 0000FFFFH;
 ELSE (* OperandSize = 32 *)
    EIP <- [r/m32];
    FI;
 FI;
```

"EIP <- [r/m32]" this frustrates me, for example:

```
   %eax=0x100063
   (%eax)=0x00fcff10(a wrong address)
```

I need to take the value of `%eax` directly rather than access to the address 0x100063 to get 0x00fcff10.
Doesn't it conflict with the manual?

What should I do if the r/m refers to an address?
`eip=M[r/m]` or  `eip=M[M[r/m]]`?

Comment: Your processor manual must be quite old, time to update it.

Answer (score 2):

Written down quite confusingly..

What it actually does is that the value of the `r/m` operand is written to `eip`. Whether that's directly the value of a register or a memory operand depends on which kind of `r/m` operand it is, as determined by the [mod R/M byte](http://www.sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm.htm) which encodes it (specifically on the `mod` field).

So, `FF E0` for example would be `jmp eax` (not from memory). `FF 20` would be `jmp [eax]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the "Intel IA32 Architecture Software Developers Manual Volume 2"

```
IF near jump
  THEN IF near relative jump
    THEN
      tempEIP ← EIP + DEST; (* EIP is instruction following JMP instruction*)
    ELSE (* near absolute jump *)
      tempEIP ← DEST;           **<----- this is what you expect to happen**
  FI;
  IF tempEIP is beyond code segment limit THEN #GP(0); FI;
  IF OperandSize = 32
    THEN
      EIP ← tempEIP;            **<----- here it is assigned**
    ELSE (* OperandSize=16 *)
      EIP ← tempEIP AND 0000FFFFH;
  FI;
FI:
```

The /4 suffix means that the REG/OPCODE field of the Mod/RM byte is used for extended opcode length, 11 bits instead of 8 bits. So a direct jump to the value of EAX is constructed of the follwing values:

```
REG/OPCODE = 100b = 4
MOD = 11b = 3
R/M = 000b = 0
==> ModR/M Byte (in Hexadecimal) = E0h  (taken from Table 2-2. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte)
```

Final result for JMP EAX is FF E0