# Relative jump not pointing to in-range address

Tags: x86-64, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida, hexdump

Note: Binary is obfuscated. I know that i can take the `qword` address and use that with the `0x1b0` but I'm confused as to why my approach below isn't working.

So I have this disassembly here. I'm trying to figure out how IDA is calculating this jump. After reading the intel instruction manual, I figured out that it's a relative jmp. So, I take the address `0x1409C9B91` and add 5 bytes to it to get the `rip`. Then I add the last 4 bytes to it in little endian which results in `0xFF8216B2`. So `0x1409C9B91 + 0xFF8216B2` gives me `0x2401EB243` but that's not anywhere in my address space. Did i do something wrong?
[image]

[image: Disassembly]

Comment: ff8216b2 needs to be sign extended.

Comment: `ff8216b2` is the 2's complement bit-pattern for `-8251726`, a negative number near 2^23 (as you can see from the top 9 bits being 1, then 3 zeros in the `8` nibble and some more in the next).  Possible duplicate of [Why does jmpq of x86-64 only need 32-bit length address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26955200)